# Video streaming by ESP32

Tags: esp32

I'm making an Arduino car and controlling it with a game-pad by bluetooth.  I want to have a live video from it by using ESP32 board and ov7670 camera or vc0706 camera. How can I do this ??

Comment: You start by reading the docs, running the examples, doing your own test and finally, implementing your solution. If you have some especific problem along the way, you ask here.

Comment: I don't know how to strat

Comment: Start with checking how feasible your requirements are (I guess Arduino and a camera is not feasible, same as esp32 for live video), but try and you will find out.

Comment: @MatsK - Are you sure its not feasible on an ESP32?  I can't find any examples, a but 240MHz dual core should be able to stream low res video I would have thought.

Comment: My bad, I missed that it was ESP32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documents and information of arducam library it may help you.....
This lib uses to connect with OV5640 5MP Camera and in its examples you may got your answer...

Comment: There is only one sort of ESP32 type board supported by Arducam as far as I can see and it still seems to be limited to still images.